# Gson.fromJson() always returns null

Tags: java, json, http, gson

I'm trying to deserialize some JSON to a generic class. The structure is roughly as follows:

```
public abstract class AbstractRequest implements Constants
{
    public abstract Class<?> getClazz();
}


public class GetTransaction extends AbstractTransactionRequest
{
    @Override
    public Class<Transaction> getClazz()
    {
        return Transaction.class;
    }
}
```

And the `Transaction` class is as follows:

```
public class Transaction implements Serializable
{
    @SerializedName("_id")
    private String id;

    private int amount;

    @SerializedName("details")
    private Map<String, String> transactionDetails;

    private class Details {
        private String issuer;

        @SerializedName("redirect_url")
        private String redirectUrl;

        @SerializedName("approval_url")
        private String approvalUrl;
    }
}
```

All classes are slightly more complicated but I removed irrelevant variables.

Here's a JSON sample:

```
{
    "_id": "2740096e-58a0-4677-8947-84fcc54cfaad",
    "amount": 456,
    "details": {
        "issuer": "MYBANK",
        "redirect_url": "https://example.com/redirect/MYBANK",
        "approval_url": "https://example.com/v1/transaction/2740096e-58a0-4677-8947-84fcc54cfaad/MYBANK/authorize"
    }
}
```

Now, I deserialize this code by doing

```
response.setData(Gson.fromJson(this.getResponse(), this.request.getClazz()));
```

Where `setData` accepts a `Object`, and `getResponse` returns the JSON as a `String`. I then do `(Transaction) response.getData()` which casts data to a `Transaction`. However, this is always null. Can anyone tell my why?

Sorry for the potentially confusing code!

Comment: You seem to have a bug somewhere in your code you haven't provided: `gson.fromJson(yourJsonHere, Transaction.class);` works perfectly.

Comment: @LyubomyrShaydariv Solved it! There was also a 'geo_location: []' in the JSON. The class variable for that in `Transaction` was a String instead of a String array. Silly mistake. Wish Gson would be able to tell me what was wrong somehow.

Comment: Well... Your question does not reflect your issue at all: no full JSON (nothing like `geo_...`), no full mapping class (nothing like `geo_...`), and too much code that could be just peeled off. Regarding Gson: Gson detects expected type and actual JSON token mismatch: adding the root JSON property `geo_location: ["foo"]` will fail during `Transaction` deserialization with something like `Expected a string but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 2 column 22 path $.geo_location`. By the way, you need `git mv src/main.java src/main` to make the maven-compiler-plugin work with its default configuration.